# How to create an object using same type of object

Tags: java

I wonder if it is possible to get a new instance of an object, using other object of the same type.

```
public class Vegetable{
    private int ...
    //a lot of fields
    public Vegetable(Vegetable v) {
        //some magic here
    }
}
```

I am looking for an option, where i wouldn't copy each single field manually in the constructor, but rather use something like **super(v)**.

Comment: I think this would lead to an infinite recursion...

Comment: Do you mean you want to clone an existing object?

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you want to do this? What is the higher-level goal?

Comment: @joaquin there would have been no reason for that.

Comment: @SeanBright Assume i have parent class B and child class C. Class B logicaly refers to a dataobject, while C refers to something i want to handle on my GUI. There is a place in my code, where i use 'public class AbstractFoo <T extends A> extends Foo<T>'. I want to be able to use my AbstractFoo with all B-s, that extend from A, and some C-s, that extends from B-s. The problem, that B class has constructors, that base on JSONObject or JsonString. That's why i want to create an instance of C using an object of B-type. This would save me an overhead creating per-field constructor in B.

Comment: Well that cleared things up. Thanks.

Comment: @SeanBright appearently, i have to remove 'T extends A' and just leave it as 'T'. This would work, but also weaken the logical relation. Sometimes not everything designed can be implemented :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java does not provide a default copy constructor.

However, Java does provide a method `Object.clone()`. You can call it on instances of classes that implement Cloneable. Otherwise, it will throw CloneNotSupportedException.

The default implementation creates a **shallow copy**. If your object contains references to other objects, only the references are copied. This is usually not what you want. To create a deeper, more independent copy, you can extend the default implementation.

You can create your own copy constructor, and this is sometimes useful. However, unlike `clone()`, a copy constructor will not necessary create another instance of the same class. A copy constructor for class T will always create a T, even if it's passed an instance of a subclass of T.